# AttributeError: tuple object has no attribute read_note()

Tags: python-3.x

OK So I have created 2 classes called Note and Notebook.

```
class Note:
    """ A Note """

    note_number = 1

    def __init__(self, memo="", id=""):
        """ initial attributes of the note"""
        self.memo = memo
        self.id = Note.note_number
        Note.note_number += 1

    def read_note(self):
        print(self.memo)


class NoteBook:
    """The Notebook"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.note_book = []

    def add_notes(self, *args):
        for note in enumerate(args):
            self.note_book.append(note)

    def show_notes(self):
        for note in self.note_book:
            note.read_note()


n1 = Note("First note")
n2 = Note("Second note")
n3 = Note("Third note")

notebook1 = NoteBook()
notebook1.add_notes(n1, n2, n3)
notebook1.show_notes()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Alan/Python3/Random stuff/notebook revisions.py", line 47, in <module>
    notebook1.show_notes()
  File "C:/Users/Alan/Python3/Random stuff/notebook revisions.py", line 38, in show_notes
    note.read_note()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'read_note'
```

How come I get an attribute error? I want my show_notes() method to read all the notes in the notebook1 list.

Also if I print the following statement my result is the cryptic message:

```
print(notebook1.note_book[0])


(0, <__main__.Note object at 0x00863F30>)
```

How would I solve this problem to not produce the weird cryptic message and to print the strings "First note", "Second note" and "Third note".

Comment: Read and apply https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  Remove the fluff (the .str method) and include the essential .add_note methods.  Then include the error message.

Comment: Thanks Terry I've edited the post and hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: After copy, paste, and run, I get the same error.  Now I can answer questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1. Why the exception?  As I suspected, the exception results from a bug in `.add_notes`.  `enumerate(args)` turns notes into tuples containing a serial number and a note.  This is wrong because notebooks should contain notes, not tuples, because notes already have a serial number, and because each call to add_note, and hence, enumerate, restarts at 0.  Change add_note to

```
    def add_notes(self, *args):
        self.note_book.extend(args)
```

and `notebook1.show_notes()` produces what you seem to want.

```
First note
Second note
Third note
```

Q2. Better representation?  For `print(notebook1.note_book[0])` to print a *tuple* is wrong regardless of the content of the tuple.  For testing, that line should have been part of the original script, just before the last line.

Printing a tuple prints the repr() of each element, so a custom `__str__` will be ignored.  With `add_noted` corrected, it now prints just the representation of the note.

```
<__main__.Note object at 0x00863F30>
```

To improve that, add back the `__str__` method I asked you to delete, or a version thereof.  I suggest you name it `__repr__` instead, though.

```
def __repr__(self):
    """ gives string of initial atrributes"""
    return "Memo: {0}\nNote number: {1}\n ".format(self.memo, self.id)
# Note 1: First note
```

If you only define `__str__`, then `__repr__` is still the mostly useless default (as above).  If you define `__repr__`, then the custom function is used for both repr() and str(), the same as if you added the line `__str__ = __repr__` after defining the latter.

Comment: Thank you that was a very thorough answer!